# How to Rebuild All Configurations & All Target Platforms in All Projects?

Tags: delphi, build

I am using Delphi XE3. Is there a way to batch rebuild all configurations(such as both “Release” and “Debug”) for all target platforms(such as both “32bit” and “64bit”) in all projects? I can only find “Build All Projects” menu item which can build only the active configurations for the active platform in all projects, not all configurations and all target platforms.

Thanks

Comment: The IDE is the wrong place for build automation. You should be scripting this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what *Build Groups* are made for. In the Project Manager click the button *Build Groups*

[image: Build Groups image].

This will open the *Build Groups* panel where you can select which projects in the current project group shall be made for which platform and with which configuration. To select the platforms and configurations you click into the relevant field for the project and click again to switch into edit mode.

[image: select platforms]

Clicking on the ellipsis button will open a dialog where you can select each platform available for this project.

[image: platform selection]

Do the same for the build configurations.

Then you can *compile*, *build* or *clean* this *Build Group* with one click on the appropriate button.

[image: build group buttons]

Of course you can have several Build Groups with different settings for different purposes.

Comment: I just do as follows:
1. Show the "Build Groups" panel
2. Add a new build group. By default, the active projects in the current project groups are added.
3. Then I cannot find a way to add more projects. For example, the active project is "MyProject-Win32", then I want to add one more project called "MyProject-Win64" to the current build group, but cannot find a way to do that. The help manual also not provide enough information.

Comment: Select the platform entry of a project and then click again to switch into edit mode. Then click the ellipsis button and you can select the platforms to build for. Same with the configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, much more better than Delphi XE3's help manual!

Comment: I find a problem. How to save the build group? After I create a build group, there are no ways for me to save it. The "Save All" button for the project is disabled. Thus after I exit Delphi then restart it and reopen the same project, the build group disappears and I have to recreate it again and again. Is there a way to solve the problem?

Comment: Build Groups are stored in the _groupproj_ file, but only when "Autosave Project desktop" is checked.

Comment: Do you mean "Autosave Project desktop" on Tools > Options > Environment Options ?

Comment: I figure out the problem. I am trying to open a Delphi 5 project in Delphi XE3. XE3 create a temp project group automatically. It seems that XE3 will not save the build group to the temp project group. But after I save the temp project group to a new groupproj file, then the build group will be saved into the new groupproj file correctly.