# Save Build Groups in Project for C++Builder 11 (RAD) IDE?

Tags: c++builder

I setup `Build Groups` in a project but when I close the project and open again, it's gone.  How do I save it with the project?   Note that I enabled `Tools/Options/Saving and Recovering/Save project desktop when closing` but still doesn't save them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47827673/#comment82809389_47828352 "*Build Groups are stored in the groupproj file, **but only when "Autosave Project desktop" is checked**.*" Been a long time since I last used Build Groups, so can't confirm this.

Comment: Where is "Autosave Project desktop" - only thing i found was the "Save project desktop when closing" ?